# How to pull PostBack data into a dynamically added UserControl (.NET)?

Tags: c#, .net, viewstate, dynamic-controls

I have a Panel on my Page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlTest" runat="server" />
```

Then I dynamically add a TextBox to it on Page_Load:

```
    TextBox simpleTextBox = new TextBox();
    pnlTest.Controls.Add(simpleTextBox);
    simpleTextBox.ID = "SimpleTextBox-1";
```

Is there a way to pull in the information typed in this TextBox without pulling it directly from Request.Form?  I thought I could do something like this after I added it again:

```
lblPresentResults.Text = myTextBox.Text;
```

I know this example seems contrived, but I figured I'd try to eliminate all the other variables in my specific application, especially to ask a question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the textbox before viewstate loads, such as in Page_Init, and you should be able to do this.

Comment: Is doing this in a UserControl's Page_Init the same as doing it on the actual Page's Page_Init?

Answer (score 2):

Just create the text box on `Init` or `PreInit` rather than Load, so that it exists in the page *before* ViewState is restored.  Then ASP.Net will update it for you automatically.